# Python3 Popen: Do I have to use .encode() every time?

Tags: string, python-3.x, pipe, subprocess

I've got a program for testing another program.  It uses Popen like so:

```
testProgram = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

In python2, I send an instruction to `testProgram` like so:

```
testProgram.stdin.write("count "+vals[0]+"\n")
```

In python3, write wants a bytes-like object instead of a str. I think this requires me to use something like `testProgram.stdin.write(("count "+vals[0]+"\n").encode("utf-8"))` for every write, but I'm obviously not going to do that.

**Is there a simple way to make Popen's stdin work as text streams in python3, or should I just stick to python2?** The argument `universal_newlines = True` [looks like it should work](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), but for me, the program just freezes at `result = testProgram.stdout.readline()`.

Comment: What is the program and what are you inputting?

Comment: It's an "Event Counter".  I don't really know what that means, but I know what it's supposed to do. It's supposed to read in an AVL tree from a file, then check stdin for further instructions.  The script inputs a few thousand instructions, and makes sure that the entries are correct, and that the size of the tree doesn't grow larger than necessary.

Comment: `universal_newlines = True` should  work so the only thing I cam think of is  there may be some encoding issues https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding

Comment: Then maybe I've asked the wrong question.  If `universal_newlines = true` is the correct answer, then something about `result = testProgram.stdout.readline()` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `universal_newlines=True` is the correct solution, but in python3, the input doesn't automatically flush at each newline unless you pass `bufsize=1` to Popen.

In order for the program to work in python3, the Popen line became:

```
testProgram = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True, bufsize = 1)
```

Comment: `for line in testProgram.stdout` should do the same

Comment: 1- you could wrap the binary streams using `io.TextIOWrapper()` if `universal_newlines=True` is not enough in your case 2- you could use `print("count", vals[0], file=testProgram.stdin, flush=True)` to flush the stdin buffer (`bufsize=1` may be ignored on old Python 3 versions). In general, you should organize your script to work with the stdin/stdout pipes concurrently (using threads or async.io) otherwise a deadlock may happen unless your writes to stdin are not perfectly in sync with your reads from the stdout (it is very fragile)

Comment: @J.F.sebastian Good to know about `bufsize=1` not working in older versions. As for concurrency, I don't see why it's needed here.  I write something to stdin, the subprocess gets it, does work, and puts something in stdout. Reading stdout is blocking, so it doesn't seem like it matters how long it takes the subprocess to give the output; the program will wait for it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `for line in x.stdout` is no good.  It would try to read everything until it reached EOF.

Comment: @Kenkron If you don't know when to stop reading the stdout then a deadlock may happen if you don't read/write concurrently to the pipes: your parent script may be blocked reading stdout while the child process waits for the next input at the same time—deadlock. If you know when to stop reading: it is a case that I've called "perfectly in sync" above (it may work but is very fragile against an unexpected output e.g., due to some error that seems likely in tests). If you need to pass the input only once and then read stdout until EOF then just use `output = process.commmunicate(input_data)[0]`.